# Error when installing Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Pavilion

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am trying to make a dual-boot setup on a HP Pavilion Laptop.

Some data about the laptop (in case this might help):

- Intel i5 processor
- 512 GB SSD + 32 GB Intel Optane memory
- 8 GB SDRAM
- Windows 10
- NVIDIA GeForce

I am new to installing a dual-boot and followed this guide: https://medium.com/@kimma1261/a-simplified-guide-to-installing-dual-boot-of-windows-10-and-ubuntu-for-absolute-beginners-16c09cd21aa7

Key steps I have done:

- Downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 onto a USB stick using Etcher (I have also tried Rufus)
- Verified that my old Lenovo laptop can "Try Ubuntu without installing" from the USB stick
- Created a partition of the C: drive
- Disabled "Turn on fast startup"
- Disabled "Secure boot"

The issue:
When I try to start "Try Ubuntu without installing" on the HP Pavillion Laptop, error messages appear and I can't figure out what to do. Also, if I choose "Install Ubuntu", the error messages appear before the installation guide actually appears, but choosing the "Something else" option or the "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" the partition I created in Windows is not find. So there seems to be something wrong no matter which option I choose.

I would be very thankful for any help, and can provide further information if that helps.

Here is an image of the error messages  when choosing "Try Ubuntu without installing":
[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qqnw.jpg)

EDIT:
I have checked the following:

- HP Laptop is set to UEFI
- HP Laptop has RST (RAID)

I could not find the option to change between RAID and AHCI in the Boot menu, and if this message board is correct it seems that I will be stuck with RAID. https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/HP-Pavilion-dv7-6103ei-AHCI-RAID/td-p/4178440

Comment: "Something else"is the best choice when you can get to it; "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" would have been best choice had you followed the preferred procedure from Ubuntu, https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 . However, we have to get you to "Try Ubuntu without installing" first, all else is secondary until we can do that. Is your BIOS/firmware of that HP laptop set to UEFI or Legacy BIOS booting? Is ACPI set instead of RAID? Please check those 2 things, & then click [edit] and advise. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].